# rails 4.2.6 authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic problems in update/put/patch method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, csrf, curb

Hi guys i have problems with `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`, here is the code:

```
def authenticate
  puts "here 1"
  if authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Qontak') do |username, password|
      puts "here 2"
      @user = User.find_by(public_key: username, private_key: password)
    end
  else
    puts "here 3"
    render json: {message: 'Unauthorized'}
  end
  puts "here 4"
end
```

when i debug for update method the console prints out:

```
here 1
here 4
```

Then there is error log like this:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

after that i was redirected to `show route` and the console successfully printed like this one

```
here 1
here 2
here 4
```

i was wondering what happened to `put/patch/update` method while authentication ? why it fails but not show/get route ?

Comment: try changing unauthorized line to `return render json...`

Comment: still give same results

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. didn't fuly notice the error. 401 Unauthorized means that your authentication returned nil so it was not able to authenticate. But I don't know if this is relevant to your question (since it probably should've logged here 2)